# html -split a page into desired shapes as divs?

Tags: css, html, canvas

I'm trying to split a page into different shapes, as shown in this image:
[image: desired shapes]

The problem is I'm trying to create divs as the shapes in the image so I can put content in them and by changing the css styles change their colors and give them effects with JavaScript,
Searching the net I did come across some sites like [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) to create CSS Triangles, but that's not exactly what I want because I cant put content in such a div and cant get exactly the shapes I need, I was thinking maybe I could get such results with the  element, but i don't really know if its logical to use  instead of  and can get the effect I want?

**is there a way to divide an Html page into any desired shape?**

Comment: Are the shapes going to remain the same size, or do they need to expand with content? And if so, do the other items need to expand with them?

Can you also show us what you want the text to look like inside the container?

Comment: What you have tried? Can you post your code?

Comment: @coldcoder : they need to be animated and expanded on a mouse event. The content is going to be scattered angled SVG drawings and text inside the divs, I dont actually have an example yet, but it can be anything. I can also come along with the shapes not doing any animations and not expanding,

Comment: @suresh.g I haven't got a clue yet to how to divide my page yet, nothing special as I stated I did come across [link](www.http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) but wasn't helpful due to the face that it only creates triangular shapes and not divs and I don't really know if the <canvas> element is the right choice and can be done by the element or not...

Comment: Yeah, I think your only options for what you're looking for is canvas type setups and using the Raphael JS API. You can use [CSS3 rotate text](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/) to rotate the text, but it is only supported in later browsers. You may want to think about silverlight or flash for this.

Comment: @coldcoder : Here is an example I found, I'm wondering how they have managed to create the Triangle and filled it up, I know it's done by the <canvas> element, _but how??_ 
[link](http://beta.rallyinteractive.com/)
BTW I really don't want to use flash or silverlight or any other solution that needs a third party plugin.

Comment: To be honest I'm no canvas expert but looking at their view source you can see the working JS files commented out. They have it minified at the end result. I suggest looking into the [Raphael API](http://raphaeljs.com/) as it gives support for older browser that don't support canvas. You'll see he has a ton of examples and if you learn it there is no limit to what you can do with it.

Comment: So this is interesting and similar to what you want:
http://www.css3shapes.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm, you can use css3 transformations (rotation):

HTML:

```
<div class="shape1">
    <div class="shape1-content"> ... </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.shape1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.shape1-content {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Of course, you shoud apply other styles (position: absolute, and others).

UPDATE:

copy'n'paste this code to see live example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .wrapper {
                border: 1px solid #ff8888;
                height: 480px;
                left: 50%;
                margin: -240px 0 0 -320px;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                width:  640px;
            }
            .shape1 {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
                   -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);

                background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid black;
                height: 50%;
                left: -25%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 70%;
                width: 150%;
            }
            .shape1-content {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
                   -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);

                padding-left: 230px;
            }
            .shape2 {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
                   -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);

                background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #88ff88;
                bottom: 244px;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                right: 50%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .shape2-content {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
                   -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);

                bottom: 10px;
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
            }
            .shape3 {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
                   -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);

                border: 1px solid #8888ff;
                bottom: 40%;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                right: 20%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .shape3-content {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
                   -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);

                   bottom: 50%;
                   position: absolute;
                   right: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="shape3">
                    <div class="shape3-content">Hi there!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="shape1">
                <div class="shape1-content">Hi there!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="shape2">
                <div class="shape2-content">Hi there!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think there are two problems with this approach, first of all does it work with all the browsers and secondly still how would divs as shown in the image?

Comment: @Farzan define "all browsers". support for css3 transforms is in ie9+ http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: @Jacky Qwerty: could you explain to me how the wrapper part works, I really don't understand the "margin: -240px 0 0 -320px" part?

Comment: @Farzan: never mind, i just wanted to align example box to center of the screen. But you can look at the "overflow" property, in this example it hides unnecessary parts of blocks.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can't do that with CSS until the CSS Shapes and Exclusions stuff mentioned here gets added to browsers in a few years http://corlan.org/2012/03/16/css-bleeding-edge-features/

For now basic CSS3 will allow you to create shapes and rotate them, but not with much precision. Your best bet may be to use to use SVG.

Here's an example of using SVG to make a puzzle out of an existing image:
http://lavadip.com/experiments/jigsaw/

A lot more information can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Tutorial

As mentioned earlier you can use a library like http://raphaeljs.com/ to help with creating your SVG graphics.

A warning though it might be a pain in the backside to do :-p