# How can I do triangel div in one row using bootstrap like this image

Tags: html, css

I want white section and background image section in same row. Like attached image [image]

Comment: Try to provide the jsfiddle or codepen link

Comment: Similar questions: [Two-tone background split by diagonal line using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739162/two-tone-background-split-by-diagonal-line-using-css), [html -split a page into desired shapes as divs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657484/html-split-a-page-into-desired-shapes-as-divs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **clip path** property in CSS.
For more Info Refer this article:

https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/